# user control default Text property at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, silverlight, controls

I created a user control in silverlight that masked date in a textbox.

```
public class ShamsiMaskedTextBox : TextBox
{
}
```

When I drag the control from the Toolbox to a silverlight page, its default Text value is set to "ShamsiMaskedTextBox" what I want it shows empty in textbox. I set text value to empty in constructor of my user control but it doesn't work. How can I change the default text value when I dragging the control to a page?

Comment: You must have set `ShamsiMaskedTextBox` as the default value of the `Text` property in the `UserControl`, so just find where you did that and change it to `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the control is in design time:
(System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)

Then if it is set the Text property to something that looks better like empty text or something else that you would like.